# Exposing Traefik dashboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, dashboard, k3s, traefik-ingress

I know there are many similar posts. But given the slight differences between everyone's environment, I have not found a solution that has worked for me. I am trying to access the Traefik dashboard running on bare metal (pi cluster) k3s. I am using the default LB in k3s.

Other ingress provider resources have worked like ingress to the Pihole dashboard for example. When I try to access the dashboard via: https://www.traefik.localhost/dashboard/ I get an unable to connect error. I have traefik.localhost in /etc/hosts pointing to one of the LB ingress IP's, in this case .104

In theory I think the request should be gobbled up by the LB service on the respective node, forwarded to the traefik service, if the entrypoint is open (80) in this case. The Traefik service should look at the providers available, find the ingressRoute I've made, and match the hostname. Then forward the request to the service api@internal. I do not know how to check if that service is running properly or not, which would be the last step in my debugging process if I knew how.

Here is the Traefik service:

```
    kubectl describe service -n kube-system traefik
Name:                     traefik
Namespace:                kube-system
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
                          helm.sh/chart=traefik-10.3.0
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: traefik
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kube-system
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.226.223
IPs:                      10.43.226.223
LoadBalancer Ingress:     192.168.4.101, 192.168.4.102, 192.168.4.103, 192.168.4.104, 192.168.4.105
Port:                     web  80/TCP
TargetPort:               web/TCP
NodePort:                 web  30690/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.4.88:8000
Port:                     websecure  443/TCP
TargetPort:               websecure/TCP
NodePort:                 websecure  30328/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.4.88:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Here is the IngressRoute:

```
kubectl describe ingressRoute -n kube-system dashboard
Name:         dashboard
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
Kind:         IngressRoute
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-01-18T03:42:49Z
  Generation:          9
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:entryPoints:
        f:routes:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-01-23T16:46:30Z
  Resource Version:  628002
  UID:               b96eb707-b1a9-4a6c-b94f-a8b975b4120b
Spec:
  Entry Points:
    web
  Routes:
    Kind:   Rule
    Match:  Host(`traefik.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
    Services:
      Kind:  TraefikService
      Name:  api@internal
Events:      <none>
```

Dynamic config:

```
cat traefik.yaml 
---
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  name: traefik-crd
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  chart: https://%{KUBERNETES_API}%/static/charts/traefik-crd-10.3.0.tgz
---
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  chart: https://%{KUBERNETES_API}%/static/charts/traefik-10.3.0.tgz
  api:
         insecure: true
  set:
     global.systemDefaultRegistry: ""
  valuesContent: |-
    rbac:
      enabled: true
    ports:
      websecure:
        tls:
          enabled: true
    podAnnotations:
      prometheus.io/port: "8082"
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    providers:
        kubernetesCRD:
      kubernetesIngress:
        publishedService:
          enabled: true
    priorityClassName: "system-cluster-critical"
    image:
      name: "rancher/mirrored-library-traefik"
    tolerations:
    - key: "CriticalAddonsOnly"
      operator: "Exists"
    - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
    - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
```

helm chart config to modify the above helm chart:

```
cat traefik-config.yaml 
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChartConfig
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
        api:
                insecure: true 
                dashboard: true
```

What can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I also have k3s with the preinstalled traefik and default loadbalancer.

This works for me.

If you implement this, you only need to type `traefik.localhost` in your browser and it should get you into your dashboard. No need to add `/dashboard` to your url.

The middleware will convert your http request into a https request.

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: redirectscheme
  namespace: default
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-dash-http
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`traefik.localhost`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
      middlewares:
        - name: redirectscheme  
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-dash-https
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`traefik.localhost`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
```